# Alertdialog remaining alive after click

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I have a weird bug in my program which I can only explain in one way.

When I click on a certain button in my menu screen the user gets an AlertDialog which asks him how he wishes to proceed.
Whichever he chooses he is then passed on to another activity.

Thing is, than when the user exits that activity and thus returns to the menu activity, the dialog seems to be still open.
Thing is that it doesn't happen every time.

I haven't put a dismiss() in my code but I was sure that it does so automatically.

```
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(YanivMenuActivity.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Active Game");
            alertDialog.setMessage("You are in the middle of a game.\nStarting a new game will cancel that one.\nHow do you wish continue?");
            alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Start New Game", 
                      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            inGame = false;
                            startActivity(new Intent(YanivMenuActivity.this,YanivGameActivity.class).putExtra("reset", true));
                        }
                      });

            alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Continue Old Game", 
                      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(YanivMenuActivity.this,YanivGameActivity.class).putExtra("reset", false));
                        }
                      });
            alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Something even weirder just happened. The dialog is only shown when the player clicks on the Start button and there is an active game. If there is not active game then the dialog is skipped. I just had a case where there was no active game so the click went straight to the game. When the game screen exited it returned to the menu but displayed the dialog - almost as if it was remembering the click! I'll have to see if it happens again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've almost answered your own question. You *need* to call `dismiss()` just before your `startActivity(...);` call.

Answer (score 3):

Please check below code

```
 AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(YanivMenuActivity.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Active Game");
        alertDialog.setMessage("You are in the middle of a game.\nStarting a new game will cancel that one.\nHow do you wish continue?");
        alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Start New Game", 
                  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        inGame = false;
                       dismiss();
                        startActivity(new Intent(YanivMenuActivity.this,YanivGameActivity.class).putExtra("reset", true));
                    }
                  });

        alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Continue Old Game", 
                  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                       dismiss();
                        startActivity(new Intent(YanivMenuActivity.this,YanivGameActivity.class).putExtra("reset", false));
                    }
                  });
        alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Before calling start activity you have to cancel the dialog:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
alertDialog.cancel();
startActivity(new Intent(YanivMenuActivity.this,YanivGameActivity.class).putExtra("reset", false));
                        }
```

Comment: What's the difference between cancel and dismiss?

Comment: here is what i found : Typically, a dialog is dismissed when its job is finished and it is being removed from the screen. A dialog is canceled when the user wants to escape the dialog and presses the Back button.

For example, you have a standard Yes/No dialog on the screen. If the user clicks No, then the dialog is dismissed and the value for No is returned to the caller. If instead of choosing Yes or No, the user clicks Back to escape the dialog rather than make a choice then the dialog is canceled and no value is returned to the caller..SO IN UR CASE DISMISS SHOULD B USED.I STAND CORRECTED

Answer (score 0):

```
alertbox.cancel();
```

This is what you should do when you want to close your alert box. Remember to replace alertbox with the name of your alertbox.